# reverse ascending sequences in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Trying to figure out how to reverse multiple ascending sequences in a list.

For instance: `input = [1,2,2,3]` to `output = [2,1,3,2]`.

I have used `mylist.reverse()` but of course it reverses to `[3,2,2,1]`. Not sure which approach to take?

Example in detail:

So lets say `[5, 7, 10, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3]` is the input - the output should be `[10,7,5,8,7,2,3,1]`. In this example the first 3 elements 5,7,10 are in ascending order, 2,7,8 is likewise in ascending order and 1,3 also in ascending order. The function should be able to recognize this pattern and reverse each sequence and return a new list.

Comment: Can you increase the number of elements in the list and again show the output you want? Its not possible to understand what you want, there can be more cases.

Comment: "*Not sure which approach to take?*" - how many approaches have you come up with, and what makes it hard to chose between them? It's homework, probably any approach that works will be good enough .. ? This is a QA site, ask a question that will help YOU progress in solving it - just dumping "I need code to do X" is not a good question.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to find all non-descreasing subsequences and reverse them:

```
In [47]: l = [5, 7, 10, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3]    

In [48]: res = []

In [49]: start_idx = 0

In [50]: for idx in range(max(len(l) - 1, 0)):
    ...:     if l[idx] >= l[idx - 1]:
    ...:         continue
    ...:     step = l[start_idx:idx]
    ...:     step.reverse()
    ...:     res.extend(step)
    ...:     start_idx = idx
    ...:

In [51]: step = l[start_idx:]

In [52]: step.reverse()

In [53]: res.extend(step)

In [54]: print(res)
[10, 7, 5, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1]
```

For increasing subsequences you need to change `if l[idx] >= l[idx - 1]` to `if l[idx] > l[idx - 1]`

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a more elegant way to do this, but one approach would be to use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) along with `enumerate` to iterate over sequential element pairs in your list and keep track of each index where the sequence is no longer ascending or the list is exhausted in order to slice, reverse, and extend your output list with the sliced items.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

d = [5, 7, 10, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3]

results = []
stop = None
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip_longest(d, d[1:])):
    if not b or b <= a:
        results.extend(d[i:stop:-1])
        stop = i

print(results)
# [10, 7, 5, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Walk the list making a bigger and bigger window from x to y positions. When you find a place where the next number is not ascending, or reach the end, reverse-slice the window you just covered and add it to the end of an output list:

```
data = [5, 7, 10, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3]
output = []

x = None
for y in range(len(data)):
  if y == len(data) - 1 or data[y] >= data[y+1]:
    output.extend(data[y:x:-1])
    x = y

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [5, 7, 10, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3,2]
def func(data):
    result =[]
    temp =[]
    data.append(data[-1])
    for i in range(1,len(data)):
        if data[i]>=data[i-1]:
            temp.append(data[i-1])
        else:
            temp.append(data[i-1])
            temp.reverse()
            result.extend(temp)
            temp=[]
    if len(temp)!=0:
        temp.reverse()
        result.extend(temp)
    temp.clear()
    return result

print(func(data))

# output [10, 7, 5, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a **general handy method** which returns slices of an array based on condition (predicate).

```
def slice_when(predicate, iterable):
  i, x, size = 0, 0, len(iterable)
  while i < size-1:
    if predicate(iterable[i], iterable[i+1]):
      yield iterable[x:i+1] 
      x = i + 1
    i += 1
  yield iterable[x:size]
```

---

Now, the slice has to be made when the next element is smaller then the previous, for example:

```
array = [5, 7, 10, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3]
slices = slice_when(lambda x,y: x > y, array)
print(list(slices))
#=> [[5, 7, 10], [2, 7, 8], [1, 3]]
```

---

So you can use it as simple as:

```
res = []
for e in slice_when(lambda x,y: x > y, array):
  res.extend(e[::-1] )

res #=> [10, 7, 5, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1]
```